# How to use better way for Async and Await with EF Core c#

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, entity-framework-core

I know use **Async & Await** functions better query because not use Main Thread program and You can run *Multi Task* , but not clear functions when use **Async Function**  must how mach **Await function** use ?

> which query is best for performance and **Why** ?

**Explain My Question by example**

**Query 1**

```
var sumPagesBooks = _myContext.Books.Sum(b=> b.Page);
var countBooks = awite _myContext.Books.CountAsync();
_context.Books.Add(NewBook);
_context.SaveChange();
```

**Query 2**

```
var sumPagesBooks = awite _myContext.Books.SumAsync(b=> b.Page);
var countBooks = awite _myContext.Books.CountAsync();
_context.Books.Add(NewBook);
awite _context.SaveChangeAsync();
```

[Read This Document but not answered my question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

### Conclusion

if I use one function async, How mach must i use **async** function for better performance ?

> I thing for all query better way use but i am not sure !!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62004875/9212040

Comment: Is `awite` just a typo in your question, or is that actually what you're trying to use in your code? It should be `await`.

Answer (score 1):

> because not use Main Thread program

This is not exactly true. "Asynchronous" is different than "parallel".

- Asynchronous means that one thread will do something different while it waits for something else (like an SQL request). It is about how code *waits*.
- Parallel means running two pieces of code at the same time, which can only be done with multiple threads. It is about how code *runs*.

Asynchronous code can increase your *overall* performance of your application by doing other work while waiting. But it will actually decrease performance of *any one* task. But that trade-off is usually better.

That documentation you read is very good at explaining this. I am guessing that English is not your first language, so see if that documentation is available in your language by checking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/locale/?target=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: Yes I knowledge about asynchronous programing , but i mean for each query need Async function ?

Comment: You don't "need" it, no. But why would you not?

Comment: Because for each query program wait for completed task, I think true but i am not sure !!!

Comment: You always have to wait for it to complete. If you wait synchronously, the thread is locked and does nothing else while it wait. If you wait asynchronously, the thread can do other things while it waits.

Comment: Faninaly can you deice which query is better ? I understand you first better, right?

Comment: Using `async`/`await` is always better for the overall performance of your application.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry you not understand 100% me,t i mean for all query or one  line ? Please see my example

Comment: Use async always or never. There is no reason to use async only sometimes.